# mouse no longer scrolls in Sequential for OSX

Tags: macos, mouse

I'm using Sequential in OSX to view images. I used to be able to scroll large images using the mouse wheel but now it doesn't do anything. How can I use the mouse wheel to scroll images?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Magic Mouse, try setting scrolling to without momentum. I've seen several older programs (mainly games, admittedly) that can't handle the momentum and show odd scrolling behaviour when it's turned on. Usually it's like very high sensitivity, but occasionally it manifests itself as very low apparent sensitivity - which is perhaps why Sequential isn't scrolling.